# Why does this pulse generator have a voltage inverter?

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, high-speed, reverse-engineering

I am designing a fast pulse generator, inspired by [Leo Bodnar's pulse generator](https://www.leobodnar.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=295), using the [ADCMP572](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adcmp572.html) ultra fast comparator.

[image: Leo Bodnar's fast pulse generator]

It looks like a pretty simple device, using a PIC microcontroller to drive the inputs of the comparator. However, for some reason the whole board is powered using a [LT1931](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1931.html) voltage inverter. This means that the shields of the coax connectors are sitting at a negative voltage, and the output square wave switches between 0v and -0.7v.

Is there some benefit to using a negative voltage here? Does it help improve the edge quality. Or perhaps it's just a convenient alternative to using a bock/boost regulator to guarantee a 5v potential difference?

Comment: It looks like the designer never intended the product to be used with the power supplied by a grounded USB cable, but rather to be used with a wall wart kind of USB supply. It's hard to tell since he has (quite understandably) declined to provide schematics as far as I can tell.